# JavaScript ES6 Decorator Pattern

Tags: javascript, decorator, es6-class

I'm trying to implement the decorator pattern in JavaScript with ES6 Class-Syntax. Here is my approach:

```
class Dish{
  constructor(){}
  getPrice(){}
  getDes(){}
}

class Steak extends Dish{
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
  getPrice(){
    return 13;
  }
  getDes(){
    return "Steak";
  }
}

class SideDish extends Dish{
  constructor(dish){
    super();
    this.dish = dish;
  }
  getPrice(){
    return super.getPrice();
  }
  getDes(){
    return super.getDes();
  }
}

class Pommes extends SideDish{
  constructor(dish){
    super(dish);
  }
  getPrice(){
    return super.getPrice() +5;
  }
  getDes(){
    return super.getDes() + " Pommes";
  }
}
```

When I'm calling

```
var dish = new Pommes(new Steak());
dish.getPrice();
```

The result im getting is NaN but I would expect "18". Where's my fault?

Comment: Well your `SideDish` methods (that you call from `Pommes` using `super`) don't `return` anything.

Comment: `getPrice(){
    super.getPrice();
  }` makes no sense. If you don't do anything more than the super implementation, just omit the method so that it will be inherited directly. Also it is calling `Dish.prototype.getPrice`, which always just returns `undefined` - not helpful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's an issue with `SideDish`. If I try `var side_dish = new SideDish(new Steak()); side_dish.getPrice();` I get `undefined` (this is after adding the missing returns mentioned). So that would explain the `NaN`, since `undefined + 5` would result in `NaN`, but I don't know why `SideDish::getPrice` returns undefined instead of the super (maybe because it is calling it from `Dish` instead of `Steak`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like the issue is with your parent decorator `SideDish`. It currently looks like:

```
class SideDish extends Dish{
   constructor(dish){
     super();
     this.dish = dish;
  }
  getPrice(){
     return super.getPrice();
  }
  getDes(){
     return super.getDes();
  }
}
```

with `Dish` having :

```
getPrice(){}
```

This means that for the method on `Pommes` :

```
  getPrice(){
     return super.getPrice() +5;
  }
```

`super.getPrice()` is returning `undefined` (from its direct parent, `SideDish`, forwarded to `Dish`), not to `Steak.getPrice()` as you are expecting.

When I update `SideDish` to use the attached (decorated) object like:

```
class SideDish extends Dish{
  constructor(dish){
     super();
     this.dish = dish;
  }
  getPrice(){
     return this.dish.getPrice();
  }
  getDes(){
     return this.dish.getDes();
  }
}
```

and then run

```
var dish = new Pommes(new Steak());
dish.getPrice();
```

I get 18, as expected.

Comment: @Mike, I've up-voted you answer to make up for Ele's sour attitude. Can you please return the favor for my answer?

Comment: @kshetline would really love to but unfortunately it doesn’t count because my reputation is under 15. so basically that is stackoverflow telling my if I upvote your answer. I’m sorry.

Comment: I'm upvoting everybody! You get an upvote! And you get an upvote!

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `return` in `SideDish.getPrice()`.

```
return super.getPrice();
```

You also forgot the `return` in `SideDish.getDes()`.

Comment: Gee, gosh, sorry to offend Your Highness.